# GNU Makefile, c programming

Tags: c, macos, makefile, pthreads, gnu-make

my current makefile looks likes this

```
all: hello

hello: hello.o
    clang -o hello hello.o

hello.o: hello.c
    clang -Wall -std=c99 -c -o hello.o hello.c -lpthread

clean:
rm -f *.o *exe hello
```

---

How can I modify it to compile with the following:

```
clang -std=gnu99 -Wall -o hello hello.c -lpthread
```

Comment: `*exe` sounds dangerous to me, maybe you meant `*.exe`, but on Mac OS X it seems to me a bit pointless...

Comment: What exactly is your question?  Are you asking how to modify a line of text by replacing it with a different line of text?  You can use a tool called an editor.  I'm sure there are one or two for the Mac.

Comment: @Amardeep  yes i used an editor, but i get errors and tried other ways. I just thought maybe i should make the question straight forward so that its simple to understand.

Comment: @user870565, the problem is possibly that you missed starting the replacement line with a tab character (\t) which is required by the makefile format.  You cannot use spaces there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this - usually best to do the compiling is a few steps.

```
all: hello

hello: hello.o
    clang -o hello hello.o -lpthread

hello.o: hello.c
    clang -Wall -std=c99 -c -o hello.o hello.c 

clean:
rm -f *.o  hello
```

Answer (score 4):

Use

```
hello: hello.c
    clang -std=gnu99 -Wall -o hello hello.c -lpthread
```

instead of the two rules you have for hello and hello.o now.

When your program gets bigger, however, the separation of compilation to object files and linking may at some point be faster than compiling and linking everything in one go. With separated compilation and linking compilation units that are unmodified do not need to be recompiled every time.

Answer (score 1):

Your modification requires just changing a single line; but instead, you should use some variables to make it cleaner:

```
# C compiler
CC = clang
# Additional libraries
LIBS = -lpthread
# Compiler flags
CCFLAGS = -std=gnu99 -Wall $(LIBS)
# Output executable
OUT = hello

all: hello

hello: hello.o
    $(CC) $(CCFLAGS) -o $(OUT) hello.o

hello.o: hello.c
    clang $(CCFLAGS) -c -o hello.o hello.c

clean:
    rm -f *.o $(OUT)
```